# Unable to use Web Apps

Tags: firefox, webapps

Firefox not asking to install WebApps when I navigate to Google docs , Google reader. How do I rectify this.

There are few other sites that doesn't work too. But I would be happy if these 2 work for me as I have them in my daily use .

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If yes, mark it as solved so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

I will warn you now, there are a good amount of reports that Webapps is experiencing some first day bugs. In my personal experience on two computers, it works ok.

There are however a few things you can do to get them to work awhile we wait for patches to come through the Software Updater.

First, open Fire Fox, click Edit>Preferences In the General tab at the bottom, you will see Desktop Integration, make sure it is checked. There is a button that says "Exceptions...", click it and make sure there are no exceptions:

[image]

For this second tip, here isn't much documentation on if this works or not, but I find it helped me. Open the Ubuntu Software Centre, and search for "Webapps". At the bottom of the search, you will see something like "Show 57 technical items", click that. Now you will see all the Webapps, you can install the ones you want one by one. Alternatively, you can install them all by using this command,

> sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-*

[image]

Lastly, to install the Chromium extension for Unity Webapps (I didn't manage to get a single Webapp to work in Chromium), use this command:

> sudo apt-get install unity-chromium-extension

Remember thought that this is all new to Ubuntu, and that the bugs will be ironed out in the next few week through updates. Enjoy!